# how to group years?

Tags: mysql, sql

i'm trying to get third column of years with avg vacationleavehours and avg sickleaveHours.

```
SELECT AVG(VacationHours) AS 'Vacation Hours', AVG(SickLeaveHours) AS 'Sick  Leave Hours'
FROM HumanResources.employee
WHERE (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1960' AND '1969')
GROUP BY BirthDate
UNION
SELECT AVG(VacationHours), AVG(SickLeaveHours)
FROM HumanResources.employee 
WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1970' AND '1979' 
GROUP BY BirthDate
UNION
SELECT AVG(VacationHours), AVG(SickLeaveHours)
FROM HumanResources.employee 
WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1980' AND '1989'
GROUP BY BirthDate

OutPut
vacation  sick
45        42
50        45
55        47
```

I'm getting avg vacation and sick leave hours but i want third column that says which year that avg belong to. i tried group by but it's giving me all the year.

I'm looking for this output.

```
vacation  sick  BirthDate
45        42    1960-1969
50        45    1970-1979
55        47    1980-1989
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to get too fancy. You have three separate queries you're joining, so just specify the date range of each yourself, explicitly:

```
SELECT AVG(VacationHours) AS 'Vacation Hours', AVG(SickLeaveHours) AS 'Sick  Leave Hours',
    '1960-1969' AS BirthDate
FROM HumanResources.employee
WHERE (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1960' AND '1969')
GROUP BY BirthDate
UNION
SELECT AVG(VacationHours), AVG(SickLeaveHours), '1970-1979'
FROM HumanResources.employee 
WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1970' AND '1979' 
GROUP BY BirthDate
UNION
SELECT AVG(VacationHours), AVG(SickLeaveHours), '1980-1989'
FROM HumanResources.employee 
WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1980' AND '1989'
GROUP BY BirthDate
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
AVG(CASE WHEN (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1960' AND '1969' THEN VacationHours ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Vacation Hours',
AVG(CASE WHEN (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1960' AND '1969' THEN SickLeaveHours ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Sick Leave Hours',
'1960-1969' AS 'BirthDate'
FROM HumarResources.employee
UNION
SELECT
AVG(CASE WHEN (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1970' AND '1979' THEN VacationHours ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Vacation Hours',
AVG(CASE WHEN (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1970' AND '1979' THEN SickLeaveHours ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Sick Leave Hours',
'1970-1979' AS 'BirthDate'
FROM HumarResources.employee
SELECT
AVG(CASE WHEN (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1980' AND '1989' THEN VacationHours ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Vacation Hours',
AVG(CASE WHEN (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1980' AND '1989' THEN SickLeaveHours ELSE 0 END)) AS 'Sick Leave Hours',
'1980-1989' AS 'BirthDate'
FROM HumarResources.employee
```

You should try this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use MIN, MAX with CONCAT, instead as below:

```
SELECT AVG(VacationHours) AS 'Vacation Hours', 
    AVG(SickLeaveHours) AS 'Sick  Leave Hours',
    CONCAT(MIN(YEAR(BirthDate)), '-', MAX(YEAR(BirthDate))) AS BirthDate
FROM HumanResources.employee
WHERE (YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1960' AND '1969')
GROUP BY BirthDate
UNION
SELECT AVG(VacationHours), 
    AVG(SickLeaveHours), 
    CONCAT(MIN(YEAR(BirthDate)), '-', MAX(YEAR(BirthDate))) AS BirthDate
FROM HumanResources.employee 
WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1970' AND '1979' 
GROUP BY BirthDate
UNION
SELECT AVG(VacationHours), 
    AVG(SickLeaveHours), 
    CONCAT(MIN(YEAR(BirthDate)), '-', MAX(YEAR(BirthDate))) AS BirthDate
FROM HumanResources.employee 
WHERE YEAR(BirthDate) BETWEEN '1980' AND '1989'
GROUP BY BirthDate
```